# How to consume TDatasource Component by coding returned through delphi webservice in a delphi VLC Form

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-2010

I have made a cgi web service. The code is below:

```
unit MyServicesImpl;

interface

uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns, MyServicesIntf,
  Data.DB,
  Data.SqlExpr, SQLConnection1, Data.Win.ADODB;

type
  { TMyServices }
  TMyServices = class(TInvokableClass, IMyServices)
  public
    function TestFunction(): TADODataSet; stdcall;
  end;

var
  ConnString: string;
  objTADOQuery: TADOQuery;
  objTSQLDS: TDataSource;
  objDS: TADODataSet;
  objTable :TADOTable;

implementation


function TMyServices.TestFunction: TADODataSet;
var
  objTSQLConnection1: TADOConnection;
var
  conStr: string;
begin

  objTSQLConnection1 := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  conStr := 'Provider=sqloledb;' + 'Data Source=Kays-serv64-01;' +
    'Initial Catalog=Test;' + 'User Id=sa;Password=Kays@India';
  objTSQLConnection1.ConnectionString := conStr;
  objTSQLConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;

  objTSQLConnection1.Connected := True;

  if (objTSQLConnection1.Connected) then
  begin
    objTADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
    objTSQLDS := TDataSource.Create(nil);
    objDS:= TADODataSet.Create(nil);
    objTable:= TADOTable.Create(nil);
    objTable.TableName:='expediads';
    objTADOQuery.Connection := objTSQLConnection1;
    objTADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'select * from expediads';
    objTADOQuery.Prepared := True;
    objTADOQuery.Active := True;
    objTSQLDS.DataSet := objTADOQuery;
    objDS.DataSource:=objTSQLDS;
    Result := objDS;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := objDS;
  end;
end;

initialization

{ Invokable classes must be registered }
InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(TMyServices);

end.
```

Now I am trying to consume this webservice, I have used a wsdl imported. But when I used it LIke:

```
Procedure TForm3.TestFunction;
var
  vMyService: IMyServices;
var
  objDataSource: TDataSource;
var
  objNewDS: IMyServices1.TADODataSet;
  var
  objTSQLConnection1: TADOConnection;
var
  conStr: string;
begin

  vMyService := GetIMyServices;
  objNewDS :=vMyService.TestFunction();
  end;
```

The Test function returns IMyservice1.TADODataset nad hence not compatible with Data.DB.TADODataset. Please help.

Comment: just declare objNewDS as TADODataset

Comment: [dcc32 Error] Unit3.pas(63): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Data.Win.ADODB.TADODataSet' and 'IMyServices1.TADODataSet'

I get this error when I declare it as TADODataset.

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible what you are trying to do here. Don't try to send the TADODataset over but the underlying data (something like an array or so)

Comment: Okey in that case If I would need such functionality where I want to bind the data coming from webservice, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that as the `TADODataSet` cannot be remoted as it would need the `TADOConnection` and such things like `ConnectionString` on the client as well as on the server.

The way to remove data using Delphi us using [DataSnap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/DataSnap_Overview_and_Architecture) with a `TSoapDataModule` on the server side containing a `TClientDataSet` which gets populated from the `TADODataSet` using a `TDataSetProvider`, and a on the client side a `TSoapConnection` plus `TClientDataSet` on the client.

DataSnap then will perform all the read/update traffic for you using SOAP (i.e. XML over HTTP).

See the [DataSnap videos from Pawel Glowacki](http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/delphi-labs) to get an idea on how to set this up, then read the documentation at [Creating multi tiered applications Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Creating_multi-tiered_applications_Index).

Note that for DataSnap, you need to have the Delphi Enterprise as minimum edition, and this won't work with a CGI webservices.

Another solution (less options, but gets the data across from the server to the client), is to expose the `TClientDataSet`'s internal data as XML, provide that through a method on your CGI Web Service, than on the client side put that XML into a `TClientDataSet` again.

I'm not sure if that is within the Delphi licensing terms (they might prohibit using `TClientDataSet` for doing multi-tier work), but it should work.

Comment: That was good but can you please elaborate little more as I am new to this technology.

Comment: For elaboration, the answer would get really long. You should watch the videos I mention. That's way faster, and probably more clear (: